# What's the best way to turn HTML pages into Twig templates?

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I have to do a school project that's basically a website.

Our client asked my team for a preview of the design. However, by then, my colleagues and I didn't know anything about Symfony.

So we first created a static HTML website (with CSS and JS libraries) to work on the design of the website.

Once we had agreed on the final design, we had to make the website dynamic.

After learning about the basics of Symfony in class, we decided to go for this technology.

So my question is: what's the best way to "turn" my team's static website into Twig templates ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can break up the logical sections into template files, name them appropriately, replace the static content with dynamic content, and load them as views?  It's going to have to be a manual process.  There's no silver bullet to turning static HTML pages into template files.

Comment: Take a look at https://twig.sensiolabs.org/ and read through the docs and examples. You should be then able to determine how to turn your particular static website into dynamic, templated equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts) You begin by the global site template, containing the layout and the parts that won't change much. (menu, header, footer, etc..)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Test Application{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            {% block sidebar %}
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can render your specific page rendering content through the blocks you need:

```
{# app/Resources/views/blog/index.html.twig #}

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}My cool blog posts{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% for entry in blog_entries %}
        <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```